# How to add grid view items to list box on checking a check box of DevExpress GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view of devexpress control.
In my grid view i have ID,ITEM and Checkbox.
Now my issue is to add grid view items to listbox when i checked a check box in grid view.
Please help to sort this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The devexpress gridview should have an event triggered when checking the checkbox.

So it would be something like this pseudo code:

```
Handle gridview.checkbox.valuechanged e
    id = GetID(e.row)
    item = GetItem(e.row)
    itemAlreadyExists = ItemAlreadyExistsInListView(ID)

    If e.Value and not itemAlreadyExists then 
       _listView.Add(id, item)
    else
       _listView.Remove(id,item)
```